Emails disappear when sending offline in macOS Mail app
I’m encountering an issue with the Mail on macOS. When I send a reply while offline, the email often ... just disappears.
It doesn’t show up in the Outbox or the Sent folder. Occasionally, an incomplete version (maybe an auto-save) ends up in Drafts, at best.
I've tried ...

Verified draft settings and other mailbox behaviours.

Rebuilt mailbox ... many, many times.

Booted into Safe Mode and tested, but the issue persists.


I am on the very latest macOS.
Has anyone experienced a similar issue or found a reliable solution? Any help would be appreciated!
Edit – macOS 15.1 beta 7 is macOS version. I am using SMTP for sending emails and IMAP for receiving and managing them.

Maybe beta 8 will fix it.  Doesn't Apple provide a channel for beta testers to report problems?

Alas — it has been a problem for longer than the span of the current beta, and I have provided all the feedback humanly possible direct to source over the past few weeks (or longer).
